# Java Jersey Declarative Hyperlinking @Ref Annotation Use

Tags: java, rest, annotations, jersey, hypermedia

I have been trying to expand upon the example provided in Chapter 6 (Declarative Hyperlinking) of the Jersey 1.12 documentation but appear to have hit a wall with regard to the use of the @Ref annotation.

My code is as follows:

```
@Path("/offerings/{offeringId}/widgets")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class WidgetsResource {
  @GET
  @Path("/{widgetId}")
  public Response get(@PathParam("offeringId") String offeringId, @PathParam("widgetId") String widgetId) {
    Widgets widgets = new Widgets();
    widgets.setOfferingId(Integer.valueOf(offeringId));
    Widget widget = new Widget();
    widget.setId(Integer.valueOf(widgetId));
    widgets.setWidgets(Arrays.asList(widget));
    return Response.status(200).entity(widgets).build();
  }
}

public class Widgets {
    @Ref(resource = WidgetsResource.class, style=Style.ABSOLUTE)
    URI uri;
    @JsonIgnore
    private int offeringId;
    private Collection<Widget> widgets;

    public Collection<Widget> getWidgets() {
        return widgets;
    }

    public void setWidgets(Collection<Widget> widgets) {
        this.widgets = widgets;
    }

    public URI getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public int getOfferingId() {
        return offeringId;
    }

    public void setOfferingId(int id) {
        this.offeringId = id;
    }
}

public class Widget {
    @Ref(resource = WidgetsResource.class, style=Style.ABSOLUTE, bindings={
    @Binding(name="offeringId", value="${entity.offeringId}")}
    )
    URI uri;
    private int id;

    public URI getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This works fine for the URL generated for an instance of the Widgets collection object:

```
"uri": "http://localhost:65080/<app>/offerings/9999/widgets"
```

However, I want to know how I can append the id of the Widget instances within the Collection to the URL for each Widget. So,the URI generated would be something like:

```
"uri": "http://localhost:65080/<app>/offerings/9999/widgets/1234"
```

I can't seem to find a way of using the Ref annotation to achieve this without starting to hardcode the whole path value within the Widget class, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Is there a standard way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

My reading of that documentation says you could do something like this (untested!):

```
@Ref(value="/offerings/{offeringId}/widgets/{widgetId}", style=ABSOLUTE)
URI uri;
```

Comment: You should still be able to do the Bindings with this approach, though the tragedy here is that you're now duplicating the hard coded path in a every single place that a representation needs a sub resource URI. If you're doing true or nearly true REST in a large application, this could be a huge hassle if those URIs ever change.