# @Ref and @QueryParam

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I am using Jersey 1.11.1 in GlassFish and I am trying to return a URI that has an @QueryParam.

For example I want the returned URI to look something like:

```
<bar>http://car.com/star?param=XYZ</bar>
```

I have the basic @Ref like this:

```
@Ref(
    resource=Foo.class,
    style = Ref.Style.ABSOLUTE,
    bindings={}
)
@XmlElement
private URI bar;
```

but for the life of me I cannot figure out if there is a way to add the query param in there or not.

If it is possible how?  If it isn't possible any suggestions on what to do instead?

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617107/java-jersey-declarative-hyperlinking-ref-annotation-use

Comment: Not a duplicate - I am after the query params ? and &.  The other answer only covers the path /1/ type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not supported as of yet: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-688[1](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-688)

```
The jersey-server-linking module lacks of support for query parameters.

Example:
@Ref(
   value="books?page=${instance.page - 1}",
   condition="${instance.page > 0}",
   style=Style.ABSOLUTE
)
@XmlElement
URI previous;

The ? will be encoded as %3F. So it is not possible to add any query parameters to links generated by the @Ref annotation.
```